# Что значит ошибка 'function' object is not an iterator при падении pytest

Tags: python, selenium, test-automation, pytest, type-error

Пытаюсь запустить автотест, но получаю ошибку 'function' object is not an iterator
КОД:

```
    def log_in_click(self):
        #добавляю сюда данные из generator.py
        # в первой строке ставлю итератор что бы данные подставились корректно
        iterator = next(generate_person_with_valid_data)
        email = iterator.email
        password = iterator.password
        user_name = iterator.user_name
        self.element_is_visible(self.locators.LOG_IN).click()
        self.element_is_visible(self.locators.EMAIL).send_keys(email)
        self.element_is_visible(self.locators.PASSWORD).send_keys(password)
        self.element_is_visible(self.locators.ENTER_BTN).click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось нужно было поставить скобки в переменной iterator
Верный вариант:

```
    def log_in_click(self):
        #добавляю сюда данные из generator.py
        # в первой строке ставлю итератор что бы данные подставились корректно
        iterator = next(generate_person_with_valid_data())
```